# IBM i short table name in system tables

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am looking for "Short" table name (or "System Name") in IBM i system tables. I expected to find it in SYSIBM.TABLES or SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS. How can I get list of tables with both short name and long name.

While in SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS, how can I get field length. I don't see that field either, while I do see stuff like buffer, column.

Also why are some of these tables in SYSIBM, some in QSYS2. Is there any logic to names and locations and table, field naming conventions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a reason behind the various locations
[Db2 for i Catalog Views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm)

- IBM i specific (QSYS and QSYS2)
- JDBC/ODBC ANSI and ISO compatible (SYSIBM)

SYSCOLUMNS and SYSTABLE both have a `SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME` column, which is where you will find the short system name.